Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down caused by threshold for consecutive task creation reached
I'm creating some jobs in AWS Glue and I'm getting the error Job 0 canceled because SparkContext was shut down caused by threshold for consecutive task creation reached.
My scenario
Number of workers: 2
Glue Version: 4.0
Python 3
Additional settings
conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")

I need to read a table that is in an on-premises environment with approximately 1 thousand records, load it to the raw, trusted and refined layer.
I've already tried to increase the number of workers and worker type, but without success.

the parquet file is using snappy mode for compression

Try to refer to this discussion if it helps (https://repost.aws/questions/QU6ZeJf-KUQlGymokSN1oqaA/how-to-find-root-cause-of-sparkcontext-shutdown-in-aws-glue-job)
